# Font rendering with Swing on Windows 10 without AA looks broken

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

One of our applications uses Swing's Windows look and feel. On Windows 7 *without* "Smooth edges of screen fonts" in the system settings the fonts look like this:

[image: Win 7]

On Windows 10 (also *without* "Smooth edges of screen fonts") the font looks like this:

[image: Win 10]

I'm using the latest JDK 8 version (8u192). On Windows 10 the scaling factor is 100%.

How can we get the same font rendering on Windows 10 as in Windows 7?